Jeremiah 18:1-10 Why does God blame Israel for behaving the way it does, when he has created him like that?
God is the potter, but he has also created the clay. With the analogy in this passage, it appears as though God is blaming the clay for being what it is. Either he is not a good enough potter to get the result he wants, or the clay is not good enough to be made into the result he wants. In that second possibility, God can only blame himself for not being able to create clay that does what he wants to do. A potter does not ask anything of the clay - either he is not skilled enough, or the materials he has collected are sub-par.

1 This is the word that came to Jeremiah from the Lord: 2 “Go down to the potter’s house, and there I will give you my message.” 3 So I went down to the potter’s house, and I saw him working at the wheel. 4 But the pot he was shaping from the clay was marred in his hands; so the potter formed it into another pot, shaping it as seemed best to him.

The sense is not that the potter intentionally disfigured the clay, but the clay slackened in his hand. The analogy draws over to the nation of Israel.

5 Then the word of the Lord came to me. 6 He said, “Can I not do with you, Israel, as this potter does?” declares the Lord. “Like clay in the hand of the potter, so are you in my hand, Israel. 7 If at any time I announce that a nation or kingdom is to be uprooted, torn down and destroyed, 8 and if that nation I warned repents of its evil, then I will relent and not inflict on it the disaster I had planned. 9 And if at another time I announce that a nation or kingdom is to be built up and planted, 10 and if it does evil in my sight and does not obey me, then I will reconsider the good I had intended to do for it.


If everyone was programmed as robots, then we save the trouble to compare with each other the quality.

It is a very popular way of thinking these days, that behavioural problems people experience can be blamed on having been 'made that way'. A genetic flaw is supposed to be the reason, and so the person ought to be excused, or at least given some slack. This even extends to having a desire to drink lots of alcohol, or to wanting to smoke tobacco. A genetic component is supposed to be the underlying cause, and they have a "predisposition" to that, so it's not really their fault. So goes the thinking.
Apply that way of thinking to Jeremiah 18:1-10 and up comes a question like this. Yet note this point in the text - the word 'blame' is never spoken by God. He is not 'blaming' the nation for their behaviour. He is observing what the nation has decided to do, namely, to disobey their Maker, and go their own way. In response to that, he warns the nation that they will be disciplined by him. He will not turn a blind eye to prolonged rebellion against himself. He is their Maker. He will raise up other nations to correct them, and it will be a severe correction.
Yet God did not cast them off entirely. Once they humbled themselves (which happened after 70 years' captivity), he restored them. Jeremiah chapter 18 is about a human potter at his work, and Jeremiah being told to observe that, while God speaks to him regarding the nation of Israel, using the real-life situation at the potter's house as a visual-aid.
So, the answer to the question is: God says he will deal with the nation for its choice to continually disobey him. Then he will refashion them when they repent of their disobedience. The illustration is designed to speak to the nation's arrogance. It has nothing to do with any inability, or unfairness, or blame. The need is to stop being influenced in our thinking by the way modern social behaviourists speak, and to grasp the way the nation of Israel between 626 and 586 B.C. was resisting their Maker.

It's a question about justice. Another way of saying it is "How is it just that God held Israel accountable for the flaws God created in them?"
Looking at the analogy:

4 But the pot he was shaping from the clay was marred in his hands;

What was the mar/imperfection in the clay?
The imperfection in the clay/nation is disobedience.
The clay on a potter's wheel will sometimes seem to refuse to obey the direction of the potter just as the nation of Israel had refused the direction of God. In the analogy it is true that clay has no choice - but people do.

8 and if that nation I warned repents of its evil, then I will relent and not inflict on it the disaster I had planned.

God made the nation such that it could obey or disobey. Disobedience is evil.
If the nation disobeys is warned by God and then repents the imperfection is resolved.
If the nation is warned by God and choses to not repent:

10 and if it does evil in my sight and does not obey me, then I will reconsider the good I had intended to do for it.

You are correct, God is both the potter and the creator of the clay. God has control over how the clay was made. God had made the clay - the nation of Israel such that it had a choice to obey him or not.
Israel could choose to be obedient and they were not.
God warned them about the error of their choice.
They refused to repent.
It was just that God held them accountable for their decisions.
It was merciful and gracious that God warned them they were headed for destruction.


Jeremiah 18:1-10 Why does God blame Israel for behaving the way it does, when he has created him like that?

The answer lies in the fact that God allowed Israel to have free will. This was not an oversight on His part, nor does it apply any fault to Him for their moral failings. God allowed human beings to have free moral agency from the very beginning. Human beings have a spirit in them that is distinct from the Holy Spirit that comes from God. That spirit in man is the spirit of our own free will that dictates our innate desires, thoughts, and impulses.
Why did God create Israel like this?
It was His intention from the beginning to allow this to be the case, and there's a very good reason for it: He wanted Israel to come to be like Him of their own accord. God wanted them to choose to be like Him; the same applies to us today. Their freedom to choose should be used to choose right. The Holy Spirit is distinct from man's spirit, but it is up to us (as well as to Israel, who failed) to choose to surrender that self-will and disobedience and choose to let God impart His spirit to us. This process is part of the plan of God and glorifies Him.
Job 32:8 states:
"But there is a spirit in man, And the breath of the Almighty gives him understanding."
Israel was guided by a spirit of disobedience, self-will, and lack of trust in God's promises.

The sense is not that the potter intentionally disfigured the clay, but the clay slackened in his hand. The analogy draws over to the nation of Israel.

Exactly right. The issue was not with His vision, design, or competence to bring that vision to pass; the issue was with the quality of the material with which He was working. Israel was a troubled nation with the ability to choose what direction they wanted to go, and they consistently chose wrong. This was not a reflection of God, but a reflection of them. This is true of all human beings, not just the nation of Israel.
God's grace and lovingkindness are not rebuffed when the material with which He is working fails to measure up. When we choose to surrender our self-will and disobedient nature we submit ourselves to be worked with by God, as we find in II Corinthians 5:17:
"Therefore, if anyone is in Christ, he is a new creation; old things have passed away; behold, all things have become new."
God allowed Israel to have free moral agency, and they abused it. However, this perceived flaw in His design is actually an intentional example of how God allows things to happen in order to:
A) Prove the need for salvation through His Messiah
B) Lead to His ultimate glory
C) Help Israel (and mankind as a whole) to come to a healthy sense of respect, awe, and love for Him
D) Make us understand why and how we need to become like Him - not through intellectually understanding doctrine, but by applying it in our lives.
God never gave up on Israel, and He will never give up on us.

Hey David! Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! And thank you for your contribution. If you haven't already, when you get a chance, please take the  tour to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's  sections on both asking and answering questions.
